# Python Output Random Order From ReadLines()

Tags: python, random

Below is my code for reading a .csv file that contains about 25 rows. The output is the same for each row. What I want to be able to accomplish is have a random order for each "row". Here is the code:

```
f_in = open("input.csv",'r')

f_out = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in f_in.readlines():
    f_out.write('<p>' + random.choice(list(open('content.txt'))).replace("\n", "").replace(".", "").replace("?", "").strip().capitalize() + ' <a href="' +
                line.replace("\n", "").split(",")[0]+"" + '">' + line.replace("\n", "").split(",")[1]+"" + '</a> ' + random.choice(list(open('content.txt'))).replace("\n", "").strip().lower() + '</p>' + 
                #
                '<p>' + random.choice(list(open('content.txt'))).replace("\n", "").replace(".", "").replace("?", "").strip().capitalize() + ' <a href="' +
                line.replace("\n", "").split(",")[2]+"" + '">' + line.replace("\n", "").split(",")[3]+"" + '</a> ' + random.choice(list(open('content.txt'))).replace("\n", "").strip().lower() + '</p>' + 
                #
                '<p>' + random.choice(list(open('content.txt'))).replace("\n", "").replace(".", "").replace("?", "").strip().capitalize() + ' <a href="' +
                line.replace("\n", "").split(",")[4]+"" + '">' + line.replace("\n", "").split(",")[5]+"" + '</a> ' + random.choice(list(open('content.txt'))).replace("\n", "").strip().lower() + '</p>' +
                #
                '\n')    
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

What this outputs is `<p>text a link text</p><p>text a link text</p><p>text a link text</p>` which is fine and that is what I want but I need row 2 to be in a different order as well as row 3 and so forth.

For example, the first output it reads from line 1 would be column AB CD EF and what I want is say for row 2 the output to be columns EF AB CD. So for each line in the .csv file the output needs to be reordered not just AB CD EF for every single 25 lines in the .csv file.

I'm not real advanced in Python and my code could be done differently, this is just the best way I knew how to get this far. Can someone help me please with trying to get a working code that will achieve this kind of output? Thank you.

**SAMPLE INPUT DATA FROM CSV FILE:**

```
Line 1 --> Column A http://domain.com Column B my anchor text 1 Column C http://domain.com Column D my anchor text 2 Column E http://domain.com Column F my anchor text 3
Line 2 --> Column A http://domain.com Column B my anchor text 1 Column C http://domain.com Column D my anchor text 2 Column E http://domain.com Column F my anchor text 3
Line 3 --> Column A http://domain.com Column B my anchor text 1 Column C http://domain.com Column D my anchor text 2 Column E http://domain.com Column F my anchor text 3
```

CSV DATA

```
http://domain.com,anchor text 1,http://domain2.com,anchor text 2,http://domain3.com,anchor text 3
http://domain.com,anchor text 1,http://domain2.com,anchor text 2,http://domain3.com,anchor text 3
http://domain.com,anchor text 1,http://domain2.com,anchor text 2,http://domain3.com,anchor text 3
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT BY LINE**

```
Line 1 --> Column A and B Column E and F Column C and D
Line 2 --> Column E and F Column A and B Column C and D
Line 3 --> Column C and D column E and F Column A and B
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear what you are trying to do. Could you add a sample of the input and output desired from it?

Comment: I added some sample input and output data. I hope I explained that better.

Comment: It's still not very clear what you're trying to do

Comment: The input file doesn't look like CSV format to me. Please show actual lines from the file if possible.

Comment: I updated it under CSV DATA of what the .csv file looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do what I think you're asking for is to group the domain/text pairs in tuples for each row and then shuffle that list.

Here's some code that will read from a csv file, shuffle the domain/text pairs for each row, and output both a text and csv file with the shuffled rows:

```
import random
import csv

with open("input.csv") as infile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(infile)
    with open("output.csv", 'w') as outcsv:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(outcsv)
        with open("output.txt", 'w') as outtxt:
            for row in csvreader:
                random_pairs = [(row[2*i], row[2*i + 1]) for i in range(int(len(row)/2))]
                random.shuffle(random_pairs)
                outline = []
                for pair in random_pairs:
                    outtxt.write('<a href="' + pair[0] + '">' + pair[1] + '</a>')
                    outline.append(pair[0])
                    outline.append(pair[1])
                outtxt.write('\n')
                csvwriter.writerow(outline)
```

Using the csv data you supplied results in the following outputs:

**output.txt:**

```
<a href="http://domain3.com">anchor text 3</a><a href="http://domain2.com">anchor text 2</a><a href="http://domain.com">anchor text 1</a>
<a href="http://domain3.com">anchor text 3</a><a href="http://domain.com">anchor text 1</a><a href="http://domain2.com">anchor text 2</a>
<a href="http://domain2.com">anchor text 2</a><a href="http://domain3.com">anchor text 3</a><a href="http://domain.com">anchor text 1</a>
```

**output.csv:**

```
http://domain3.com,anchor text 3,http://domain2.com,anchor text 2,http://domain.com,anchor text 1
http://domain3.com,anchor text 3,http://domain.com,anchor text 1,http://domain2.com,anchor text 2
http://domain2.com,anchor text 2,http://domain3.com,anchor text 3,http://domain.com,anchor text 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need to do. I don't think I knew how to explain it very well, but you did a great job on picking up on what I was looking for. This works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to break the code out into functions; it should be significantly easier to understand and maintain.

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
import random

LOREM_IPSUM = "content.txt"
LINK_TEXT   = "input.csv"
OUTPUT      = "output.phtml"

def csv_rows(fname, **kwargs):
    with open(fname, "rb") as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, **kwargs)
        for row in incsv:
            yield row

def by_twos(iterable):
    # given (a, b, c, d, ...) returns ((a,b), (c,d), ...)
    return izip(*([iter(iterable)]*2))

def a(href, *content):
    return "<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>".format(href, " ".join(content))

def p(*content):
    return "<p>{0}</p>".format(" ".join(content))

def br():
    return "<br/>"

def main():
    with open(LOREM_IPSUM) as inf:
        lines = (line.strip() for line in inf)
        content = [line.capitalize() for line in lines if line]
    randtxt = lambda: random.choice(content)

    with open(OUTPUT, "w") as outf:
        for row in csv_rows(LINK_TEXT):
            links = [a(href, text) for href,text in by_twos(row)]
            random.shuffle(links)    # randomize order
            paras = (p(randtxt(), link, randtxt()) for link in links)
            outf.write("".join(paras))
            outf.write(br())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```